# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am really confused. I have some code:

```
public ActionResult submitSurveyQuestion(SurveyQuestion model) 
    {
        SurveyQuestion nextQuestion = new SurveyQuestion();
        nextQuestion = submitSurveyQuestionAndGetNextQuestionFromQuestion(model);
        return RedirectToAction("generateViewForSurveyQuestion", new { question = nextQuestion });
    }

public SurveyQuestion submitSurveyQuestionAndGetNextQuestionFromQuestion(SurveyQuestion currentQuestion)
    {
        SurveyQuestion surveyQuestion = new SurveyQuestion();
        surveyQuestion.Question = "question";
        //...etc, this just sets all the question properties
        return surveyQuestion;
    }
public ActionResult generateViewForSurveyQuestion(SurveyQuestion question)
    {
        //ERROR BELOW THIS LINE
        return View("SurveyQuestionType" + question.QuestionType, question);
        //ERROR ABOVE THIS LINE
    }
```

But for some reason, my code returns the error:`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` When looking through the debugger, it says that `question = null`, but I set all the properties of `question` and instantiate it, so I am really confused as to what's going wrong here.....any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in what line do you get the error? return View("SurveyQuestionType" + question.QuestionType, question); here?

Comment: You're using a RedirectToAction to hit the controller method. That sends a 302 response to the browser which then sends a request back to your controller. The `nextQuestion` object you created in `submitSurveyQuestion` is long gone by that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: so.....I need to do all this within one method?

Comment: No, it need not be one method, you just should not use `RedirectToAction()` in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `generateViewForSurveyQuestion()` directly to return the view:

```
public ActionResult submitSurveyQuestion(SurveyQuestion model) {
  SurveyQuestion nextQuestion = new SurveyQuestion();
  nextQuestion = submitSurveyQuestionAndGetNextQuestionFromQuestion(model);
  return generateViewForSurveyQuestion(nextQuestion);
}
```

[The overload of `RedirectToAction()` which you are invoking requires route parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.Object%29), which your `SurveyQuestion` object cannot properly represent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use TempData as below.

```
public ActionResult submitSurveyQuestion(SurveyQuestion model) 
    {
        SurveyQuestion nextQuestion = new SurveyQuestion();
        nextQuestion = submitSurveyQuestionAndGetNextQuestionFromQuestion(model);
      TempData["question"] = nextQuestion;
        return RedirectToAction("generateViewForSurveyQuestion");
    }

public SurveyQuestion submitSurveyQuestionAndGetNextQuestionFromQuestion(SurveyQuestion currentQuestion)
    {
        SurveyQuestion surveyQuestion = new SurveyQuestion();
        surveyQuestion.Question = "question";
        //...etc, this just sets all the question properties
        return surveyQuestion;
    }
public ActionResult generateViewForSurveyQuestion()
    {
        // TempDate[question] available here......
    }
```

Comment: `TempData[]` could be used to persist the object across invocations, but it is not necessary for this use case.